# Ternary vs. Logical Operators

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator, logical-operators

Apologies if this is a dupe, I've only seen an `or ||` comparison.

If I want to set one variable's value based on a single condition, where `b` will always evaluate to `true` (not 0, null, undefined), why would I use the ternary operator `a?b:c` over the logical `a&&b||c`? They both appear to perform the *exact* same function, although tests on jsperf show the latter being slightly faster.

What is the purpose of the ternary operator if a very similar operation and syntax outperforms it at the same task? More curiously, what does it *do* that makes it slower?

Comment: They're not the same. Check `1 ? 0 : 2` versus `1 && 0 || 2`.

Comment: That is true, perhaps I should clarify that in the far more common instance that both values evaluate to true.

Answer (score 5):

What if you want to set a value conditionally to `0` or some non-zero value?

```
var x = condition() && 0 || 1;
```

That won't work, because `0` is falsy.

```
var x = condition() ? 0 : 1;
```

will work, because evaluation does not rely on the coerced boolean values.

Comment: One exception, though this invokes my last question: if the logical operator checks for true twice, why is it faster? Wouldn't it be doing twice the checking work?

Comment: @fay I'm not sure; with something as basic and simple as *either* of these patterns, performance (to me) doesn't seem relevant. This sort of code is not what makes pages slow.

Comment: I like to learn, so application is fairly irrelevant. Though I will say it isn't to me, since I am using this for the physics portion of an HTML5 game. Running this over every instance every frame means the faster option and why it's the fastest option is useful knowledge, both because I like to learn and because it has real application in my situation.